# FolderBrowserDialog Cancel Event C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, folderbrowserdialog

I have an issue with dialog forms. Below is a section of C# code which calls the FolderBrowserDialog window. Now when I click "ok" on a folder it will close the dialog so not concerned about that so much. However does anyone know how to detect the cancel event? I have tried looking it up but all I seem to be able to find is "dismiss." Not sure that can help me.

```
    private void link1add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog(); // Opens Folderdialog
    }
```

For example something along these lines:

```
    private void link1add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.ShowDialog(); // Opens Folderdialog
        if (dialog == dialog.Cancel)            
        {
        }
    }
```

If anyone could shed some light on this I would be very greatful. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This:

```
private void link1add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        FolderBrowserDialog f = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (f.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) {
          //handle Cancel
        }
    }
```

Comment: This worked! Quite frustrating though since I thought I tried this. Thank you very much for your help I can stop pulling my hair out now.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void link1add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DialogResult dr = dialog.ShowDialog();
  If( dr == DialogResult.Ok)
  {

  } 
  else
  {
      //All other situations
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
 var res = dialog.ShowDialog();
 if(res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
 {

 }
 else
 {
     //dialog.Cancel
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no event you need to handle. Just look at the return value of `ShowDialog()`:

```
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
if ( result == DialogResult.Cancel )
{
...
}
```